# producing tokens for .docs extension files

Tags: java

i am creating a scanner for producing tokens for my program but instead of .txt i need it for .docs file extension i tried this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class myScanner {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Scanner s = null;

        try {
            s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("sample.doc")));

            while (s.hasNext()) {
                System.out.println(s.next());
            }
        } finally {
            if (s != null) {
                s.close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but the results are not the resuts i wanted to see can anyone help me thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to read the spec for the .doc format and build a parser.  Good luck.  (or use Apache POI)

Comment: Here is a link to the specifications: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313153(v=office.12).aspx, a .doc file is much more sophisticated than a .txt file and parsing it is non trivial